# How to display release year of SoundCloud track?

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

The soundcloud Api mentions 'release_year' but I can't seem to get it to display via a javascript 'append'. I have tried 'created_at' and this works but displays too much information i.e. "2012/01/16 09:23:45 +0000" - I only want to display the year that the track was released/uploaded to soundcloud.

```js
$('p', this).html(track.created_at);
```

The line above is currently working @ http://artpenleystudios.com but I only want the year.

Additional information: I am building a soundcloud audio player based on 'custom soundcloud player' https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player

I appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Moment.js is your friend. http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If date format is always the same, why not:

`$('p', this).html(track.created_at.substring(0,4));`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Date#getUTCFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCFullYear).

```
var creationDate = new Date(track.created_at);
$('p', this).html(creationDate.getUTCFullYear());
```